# ¿Como pasar, modificar,imprimir un struct dinámico desde una función?

Tags: c, esp32

El problema que tengo es que el código compila, pero al subirlo no funciona, y estoy casi seguro que el error esta en la función **printTable()**, deberia mostrarme lo que imprime la funcion printTable pero me lanza este error

[memory] Reserved memory rootTable
[database] loaded user:
user0
password0
user0@mail.com
root0
1
[database] printed user:
[database] add second user:
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400014fd  PS      : 0x00060030  A0      : 0x800dabde  A1      : 0x3ffb48a0
0x400014fd: strlen in ROM

A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0xfffffffc  A4      : 0x000000ff  A5      : 0x0000ff00
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffb4860
A10     : 0x3ffb4880  A11     : 0x00060a23  A12     : 0x00060a20  A13     : 0x00000000
A14     : 0xffffffff  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x0000001b  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff

aqui esta mi codigo

**kernel.c**

```
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "database.h"

struct root* rootTable;

void app_main(){
    
    rootTable = (struct root*) calloc(MAX_ROOTS,sizeof(struct root));
    printf("[memory] Reserved memory rootTable\r\n");
    

    rootTable[0].user = "user0";
    rootTable[0].pass = "password0";
    rootTable[0].mail = "user0@mail.com";
    rootTable[0].rank = "root0";
    rootTable[0].state = 1;

    printf("[database] loaded user:\n");

    printf("%s\n",rootTable[0].user); 
    printf("%s\n",rootTable[0].pass); 
    printf("%s\n",rootTable[0].mail); 
    printf("%s\n",rootTable[0].rank);  
    printf("%d\n",rootTable[0].state);

    printf("[database] printed user:\n");
    
    add_user(rootTable,1,"user1","password1","user1@mail.com","root1",1);
    printf("[database] add second user:\r\n");
    
    printTable(rootTable);
    printf("table printed\n");

    

    
    free(rootTable);
    printf("liberate memory\n");
    
 }
```

database.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ROOTS 10

struct root{    

    const char* user;
    const char* pass;
    const char* mail;
    const char* rank;
    _Bool state;

 };
 
void add_user(struct root*,int,char*,char*,char*,char*,_Bool);
void printTable(struct root*);
```

database.c

```
#include "database.h"

void add_user(struct root* rootTable,int id, char* user, char* pass, char* mail, char* rank, _Bool state){

    if(id > MAX_ROOTS){

        printf("[Error] Out size table\n");
        exit(0);
     }

    rootTable[id].user = user;    
    rootTable[id].pass = pass;
    rootTable[id].mail = mail;
    rootTable[id].rank = rank;
    rootTable[id].state = state;        

 }
void printTable(struct root* rootTable){

    for (int id = 0; id < MAX_ROOTS; id++){

        printf("%s",(char*) id);         
        printf(rootTable[id].user); 
        printf(rootTable[id].pass); 
        printf(rootTable[id].mail); 
        printf(rootTable[id].rank);                   

     } 
    
 }
```

Comment: Puedes ser más específico? ¿Qué debería mostrarse y qué se muestra?

Comment: No conozco el mapa de memoria del `ESP32`, pero esto: `printf("%s",(char*) id);` al inicio del bucle de tu función `printTable( )`, tiene pinta de ser lo que en mi pueblo llamamos *una burrada*. Para mostrar el valor de `id`, sería `printf( "%d", id );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, testeando tu codigo, lo que causa el `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` es la funcion `printTable`.
En especial esta linea:

```
printf("%s",(char*) id);
```

No tengo idea de por que casteas un entero a un puntero tipo `char`. Castear un entero a char no te dara su representacion en ASCII. Cambia esa linea por:

```
printf("%d/n", id);
```

Y se soluciona el core dump. Otra cosa, no es recomendable imprimir sin formato como lo haces en `printf(rootTable[id].pass)`, te sugiero algo como `printf("Mail: %s\n", rootTable[id].mail);`.

Saludos!

Comment: en efecto eso era, y que esta intentando modificar un char*, lo cual no se puede hacer en c por la memoria dinamica